# gnuplot Makefile can't find gd.h compiling from Visual Studio 2010 command prompt

Tags: visual-c++, gd, gnuplot

I am trying to compile gnuplot on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

Here are the steps I am following after unpacking the tar.gz for gnuplot 4.6.1:

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt
2. cd to the directory ..\gnuplot-4.6.1\config\msvc
3. entering the command "nmake -f Makefile

It runs for a very short period of time, then outputs

...breaders.c<302> : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gd.h' : No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ..\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Do I need to install the [gd library](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) or remind msvc where gd.h is located? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for users like me, who can't figure out how to unpack the tarball and compile gnuplot, there are platform specific binaries available which handle all of the setup.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.0/gp460-win32-setup.exe worked just fine so I can use gnuplot right away and worry about compiling it some time later.

Answer (score 0):

It is complicated to install `gnuplot` in Windows with `nmake`. There are many libraries that are required by `gnuplot`, that are intended for using in `Unix`, such as `gd`. You could try compile without gd: `--nogd`, but I think, the build should break because of missing some other libraries.

Downloading installer or prebuilt `gnuplot` is the best choice.

`Gnuplot` could be installed under Cygwin like [described here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/cygwin/part5/).

Some pre-built version of gnuplot [are compiled with `MinGW`](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Eng/winbin/).
So, you could also try to build `gnuplot` under `mingw`.